# Render UITableView during background fetch for restoration

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, uikit, background-process

I have a table which rows gets normally rendered from processes running in a background thread (not to slow down the scrolling). All works well but, when the app is launched from a background fetch, I struggle to render the table before calling the fetch completion handler. In facts it looks like the main thread (which is responsible to render the table after the reload data call) gets only processed after the fetch completion handler is called, leaving not much time for the table to render before its state is saved.

Is there a way to run a table reload data not in the main thread? Any other idea how I could make sure the table is rendered before calling the fetch completion?